# Аннотация @intDef

Tags: android, android-annotations

Пытаюсь создать свою аннотацию на основе `@intDef` , имеется следующая конструкция  - но он её не видит:

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;

@intDef(Importance.noMatter, Importance.green, Importance.yellow, Importance.red)
public @interface Importance {

    public static int noMatter = 0;
    public static int green = 1;
    public static int yellow = 2;
    public static int red = 3;
}
```

Создал через `java` класс.

Пытался через `@Annotations`, выдает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка с `@annotation` все еще остается загадкой, но основную проблему я исправил.

Дело было в том, что `@intDef` написано с маленькой буквы.

Напомню, что `@IntDef` является правильной заменой `Enum` в `Android` и гугл не рекомендует использовать последнее, поскольку `@IntDef` хранит простые инты, а не сложные объекты, которые всегда подгружаются, и занимают уйму памяти.